# Google Cloud Storage Nearline pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I was wondering if somebody knows how Google calculate the pricing for Google Cloud Storage Nearline. I mean... if they charge for upload, download, deletions, day, and so on.

Could you help me, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not the place to question like this, you can request support directly with google cloud services, they will be more than happy to help you with that kind of questions

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything in Google Cloud Storage documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#price-tables

**What google cloud storage charging for:**

> Cloud Storage pricing is based on the following components:
>
> - Data storage.
> - Network usage.
> - Operations usage.
> - Retrieval and early deletion fees for data stored in the Nearline Storage or > - Coldline Storage classes.

**Cost of Nearline Storage:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All of this information can be found on the [Google Cloud Storage Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) page.